# Input resistance of differential LNA

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, cmos

This is a wideband differential LNA. I am trying to calculate the input resistance of this circuit but the result is not anything similar to the result shown in the picture below.
Could you explain how can I get this input resistance? 
Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Link to the source: 
http://www.filedropper.com/2015awidebanddifferentiallow-noise-amplifier2

Comment: There is a formula conveniently marked in red where you can plug in some numbers and have another number fall out.

Comment: Well, what I meant is how to prove that formula not how to get numerical result.

Answer (score 1):

The basic way to find \$R_i\$ is to find the bias point of the circuit, then apply:
\$ R_i = dV/dI\$

Essentially, pretend that the voltage changes by just a little bit.  How much does the current change?  The change in voltage / the change in current will give you the input resistance.

This is called small signal analysis.  Using this technique you can convert the LNA amplifier schematic shown into a series of voltage/current sources and resistors.  You can also add capacitors but for calculating R and the gain, this is not necessary.  Including capacitors is done for frequency analysis.

Below is a picture showing the simplest FET model.

[image: small-signal-fet]

Once you have built up a suitable circuit model you can apply very simple math to determine the input resistance.

See the link for a walkthrough on using small signal analysis to analyze a simple MOS single stage amplifier; starting with differential feedback amplifier may be a bit much:
[single-stage-mos-example-ssa](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/312/handouts/Example%20A%20Small%20Signal%20Analysis%20of%20a%20MOSFET%20Amp.pdf)

Alternatively, you could apply small signal analysis on smaller pieces of the full amplifier.  Using two-port network theory you can 'characterize' the separate pieces (for example H-parameters).  Then using the parameters you can quickly analyze the whole circuit.
[two-port-wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-port_network)

Comment: Thank you. I am familiar with small signal model and I already know how to calculate input impedance of a circuit in general. However, I just get stuck with the particular circuit above. I already drew small signal models of MN1, MN2 and MP1 then with small input voltage signal then Rin = Vin/Iin. The problem is the result is not something like the formula in red box above at all. It is much more complicated. I also tried to simplify it by making assumption that some components are ideal but it doesn't result in the formula above.

Comment: You could perhaps show your work and I'm sure someone can spot the problem.